# object.assign angular 2 is not working correctlly

Tags: angular

I am using object.assign to create new copy of an object upon making any change in the new copy the changes are reflected in the original copy .but i don't want this

```
 let xyz = Object.assign({}, this.model);
```

*property i changed is deep inside the model.*

Is there any other alternative of object.assign ;as any changes in xyz reflects in original object .I know Object.assign works other way .but not sure what's wrong in my model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be something like this

```
let xyz = this.model;
xyz.obj1.prop1 = "Change";
```

The change will be reflected in **both** objects.

### OR

If you want a copy but not the refernce to the original you can go like this.

```
let xyz = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));
xyz.obj1.prop1 = "Change";
```

This will change **ONLY** the property in `xyz` and **NOT** in `this.model`

Comment: He didn't assign directly. He did use `Object.assign()`, but I thought `Object.assign()` should work because it's no longer by reference?

Comment: after wasting a lot of time, the JSON.parse() option works